# How to relate SQL tables

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables that i want check data from then perform respective tasks according to has been got.

SCENARIO

TABLES

- Jobs
- Applications

What i want to achieve is, if a job, say job1 has been applied by user1, this should be stored in the applications table. If user1 tries to apply for the same job(job1), user1 should be notified that he has already applied for the job. What i want is help on how i can go about this using PHP and SQL

Comment: You have the tables, you insert and select data and show errors. Which part of this is causing problems?

Comment: problem is, i cant find away on how to go about what i want to achieve, please read my last statement

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad a subject for Stack Overflow as it is. If you do not know how to handle databases, do read about them. The logic is simple for this task after you know the tools.

Comment: @McDonaldEgesaDonatius You should probably look for exception handling for your RDBMS.  Since, you didn't mention RDBMS name in your question. So, we can't help you.

Answer (score -1):

I understand what you really want to achieve but it is very hard to write the entire code for you.So I am just going to show you the direction on how to go about it.You will need a stored procedure which does the following :

Checks if the User has already applied for a job by this :

```
  Select Count(ApplicationId) from tblApplication where UserId=@UserId && JobId=@JobId

 if(Count >0)
 throw exception
 else
 Insert...
 end
```

This just gives the outline.Do your research on stored procedures first.

Comment: Unique indexes don't notify about anything, they only are constraints to keep data unique. Errors in uniqueness should never be used to test if data is already present, especially when you can deny the user from ever applying for a job second time. Not to mention this SQL command doesn't create an unique index.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen - well said, I can not express it better

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen- Yes,it struck me a little late.Edited my answer